# Command view can't see any dbgprint message

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am analysing HEVD (a driver app, debug version) on my host Windows 10 1803 and I use Windbg Preview from Microsoft Store.

The debug target is Win7 Pro x86 SP1 in VMWare.

No matter I try `ed Kd_DEFAULT_MASK 8` (or 0xf or 0xffffffff), or add DEFAULT (value 8 or 0xf or 0xffffffff) at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter`, it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the driver app is working. But I can't receive any dbgprint message.

---

Add:

I use virtualkd to open the debug port(I think it doesn't matter and even if I don't use virtualkd to open the debug port, it still doesn't work)

And when I use the regedit method, it will have the error message `Fail to read system\currentcontrolset\services\Lmhosts\Parameters\EnableUserMode, error=2`

---

Add:

Thanks for **@Thomas Weller**'s reply.

It's strange, only if I run debugview at the debug target machine I can receive the dbgprint at the windbg preview in my host machine. Does anyone know why?

And there is another not important question: after I input command, there is usually a output message `DBGHELP: HEVD is not source indexed` as you can see in the picture. Does anyone know what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you see the debug messages using [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)? Run with admin privileges to be able to see kernel messages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DWORD value `IHVDRIVER` under  `HKLM\SYSTEM\CCS\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter` and set the value to 0xf.